# Construct a function with period $P$ whose output is either $0$ or $1$?

Tags: functions, recreational-mathematics

> I need to construct a simplest function with period $P$. (Inputs are $n\in \mathbb N$)
>
> One additional condition is that its output is either $0$ or $1$.
>
> I need it be "algebraic" and by that I mean that:
>
> - It is written down using only "numbers" (*no trigonometric functions or limits for example*)
> - You can only use operations: $+, -, \times, \div, x^t$ (*where* $x^t$
>     *stands for raising numbers to rational exponents*), also absolute value $|x|$ is allowed in the form of $\sqrt{x^2}$
> - It contains a finite number of terms.

---

### Constructions

I suspect that the function should have a  template like:

$$f(n)=\frac{1+(-1)^X}{2}$$

Where $X$ is the rest of the function. (*This is just for readability*)

For period $P=2$, I'll write $f_2(n)$, then

$$X=n$$

This yields: $0,1,0,1,0,1\dots$

For period $P=4$, I'll write$f_4(n)$, then

$$X=(1-(\sqrt{-1})^n)^4$$

Which yields $0,0,0,1\dots$ repeating.

These are two examples I found.

---

> Can we find all such functions for any $P$ ?
>
> $$f_P(n)= \text{?}$$
>
> Let its period be some zeroes ending with a $1$ for consistency.

---

### Update - $f_{2P}(n)$

For $P>2, P=2k$, I found a recursive generalization:

$$f_{2k}(n)=\sqrt{\left(\frac{f_k(n)}{(-1)^{n/k} }+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2}+\frac{1}{2}$$

Which yields $1$ if $n=2k$ and $0$ otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without $(-1)^r$ I don't  think it's possible.

With it,
let $s(n,k)
=\frac1{n}\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}(-1)^{2jk/n}
=1$ if $n|k$ and $0$ otherwise.

Comment: Simple and useful!